# Execute a bat file with a variable name in the path

Tags: powershell

I am having a problem executing a powershell script where I want to point to different versions of a bat file based on some arguments

Hard coding the path as follows works with no issues:

```
    & 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2022a\bin\mcc.bat'  -W $command -T link:exe  ...
```

but replacing a folder name with a variable causes it to fail:

```
    $Matlab_version = "R2022a"
    & 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\$Matlab_version\bin\mcc.bat'  -W $command -T link:exe
```

with the following output:

```
 & : The term 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\%$Matlab_version%\bin\mcc.bat' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\%$Matlab_version%\bin\mcc.bat'  -W $comman ...
```

I've tried even creating a variable with the path name

```
$mcc_loc = & 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\$Matlab_version\bin\mcc.bat'
Write-Host $mcc_loc
```

which produces a string with the correct path. Any help is greatly appreciated. My dumb solution is to have an if statement for each $Matlab_version and hard code it in there but I'm sure there has to be a more elegant solution

Comment: its because you are using single quotes on that string. The variable will not be interpreted.
Try using Double quote marks instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are using single quotation marks.

variables will not be interpreted within single marks, everything will be taken as a literal string.

use double quotes instead when passing in variables mid string.

example:
[image: quotes in action]

Comment: Yes! That did the trick. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the single quote `'` to double quote `"`

> **Double-quoted strings**
> A string enclosed in double quotation marks is an expandable string. Variable names preceded by a dollar sign ($) are replaced with the variable's value before the string is passed to the command for processing.

```
$Matlab_version = "R2022a"
& "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\$Matlab_version\bin\mcc.bat"  -W $command -T link:exe
```

See [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2)